# Cyclic group and homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

"If $\langle g\rangle=G$ then the image of the homomorphism $f:G\to H$ is determined by $f(g)$, $\operatorname{Im}(f)=\langle f(g)\rangle$,but determining the image of the generator does not define a  homomorphism."

The first statement says that if a group is cyclic then the homomorphism is defined by the image of the generator but not the opposite?

Comment: Where did you find that quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G=\langle g\rangle$ then, if $f_1,f_2\colon G\longrightarrow H$ are group homomorphisms such that $f_1(g)=f_2(g)$, then $f_1=f_2$. That is, a homomorphism from $G$ into $H$ is totally determined by the element of $H$ that $g$ is mapped into.

*However*, if $h\in H$, it is not necessarily  true that there is a group homomorphism $f\colon G\longrightarrow H$ such that $f(g)=h$. That is what happens if, for instance, $G=\mathbb Z_2$, $g=[1]$, $H=(\mathbb Z,+)$, and $h\neq0$.

Comment: If I have a cyclic group and an homomorphism, so the image is totally determined by the generator. but if I have a cyclic group, I can not build an homomorphism just by looking on the images of the generators?

Comment: If $G=\langle g\rangle$ and if $h\in H$, there may be no group homomorphism $f$ from $G$ into $H$ such that $f(g)=h$.